# Why the home page is not shown?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I am working on a project, and I have some controllers there.Two of them is named "Class" and "Home" controller and the Class controller has a view named "Index" and the Home one has a view named "Index".But when I run the project in local first of all my Class/Index is shown and if I want to see the home page I should write Home/Index in the address bar.But it should show Home/Index first in running.What is the problem?!

Comment: right click the project and check properties. what is set as startup page?

Comment: Please share the content of your Global.asax file to get more help on your problem.

Comment: I have 2 projects in my solution and but the following answer solved the issue.Thanks.

Comment: @HamidReza: Hope you will vote for the answer :)

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal:Your right but I cant.It needs 15 reputation to vate an answer but mine is 14.But I will vote you up here in my comment:
Vote Up.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your RouteConfig.cs(App_Start) it should be like this,

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

***Note: Don't use the name of `Class` for custom codes. it is already defined by system.***

Comment: is that a question or an answer?

Comment: @DaveA: Don't you see this as a answer?

Comment: possibly. I could think of many reasons for this occurring. He could have a start path in his project is just one example. So I see this as a decent guess.

Answer (score 0):

Which controller is defined to run on your main root url, this all depends on your routing settings.

Please share the content of your Global.asax file to get more help on your problem.

Comment: The problem was from my RouteConfig.It was set to show Class/Index at the first.